# Heroku Rails "Application Error"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

Although my app is running with no errors locally I am getting a crash in production mode on Heroku.

> Application Error An error occurred in the application and your page
>   could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
>
> If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

I'm vey new at all of this and I can not make enough sense of the logs to figure out how to resolve this. Can anyone help me cypher through this and find the problem?

```
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305889+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305944+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305937+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305954+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305929+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305939+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305788+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305934+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305922+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.306000+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305963+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305945+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305950+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305933+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305832+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305992+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305955+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305960+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305949+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305987+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305958+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305989+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305965+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305985+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305998+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305994+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2014-07-03T18:46:43.305995+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-07-03T18:46:44.787130+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-07-03T18:46:45.301324+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/singles/edit/4" host=bergescreative.herokuapp.com request_id=727f16f2-4d68-4a60-ac85-3a8e13b2b0bb fwd="24.189.33.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-03T18:46:44.807228+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-07-03T18:49:15+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-07-03T18:49:42+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-07-03T18:49:42.205650+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-07-03T18:49:42.010780+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy abeb632 by coreytegeler@gmail.com
2014-07-03T18:49:42.010853+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v46 created by coreytegeler@gmail.com
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637148+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637183+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:468:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637163+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637195+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637159+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637209+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637251+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637146+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637164+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637202+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637144+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:48908
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637181+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637198+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637322+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637149+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637184+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `each'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637206+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637259+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637265+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637272+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637274+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637285+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637151+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637188+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `block in eager_load!'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637211+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637261+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637267+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637276+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637296+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637330+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637158+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': /app/app/controllers/links_controller.rb:34: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637190+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `each'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637249+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637262+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637269+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637293+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637325+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637161+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637192+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in
 `eager_load!'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637245+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637127+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637168+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:307:in `depend_on'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637197+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `each'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637256+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637279+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637280+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637283+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637287+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637288+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637290+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637295+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637297+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637314+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637203+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637258+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637264+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637277+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637315+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637327+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-07-03T18:49:47.637319+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-07-03T18:49:45.168372+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 48908 -e production`
2014-07-03T18:49:49.013452+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-07-03T18:49:49.021141+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-07-03T18:49:51.064834+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/singles/edit/4" host=bergescreative.herokuapp.com request_id=e722a08a-0cc9-460b-9bf8-28d678f04fd4 fwd="24.189.33.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-03T18:51:50.750302+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/singles/edit/4" host=bergescreative.herokuapp.com request_id=55d17389-9d17-4a4f-bf32-a8594973e3e0 fwd="24.189.33.4" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this controller /app/app/controllers/links_controller.rb:34: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError), you are probable missing an `end`

Answer (score 1):

**Server**

Firstly, you'll want to migrate away from WEBrick, and use something like [`unicorn`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn) or `puma` as your production server:

```
#Procfile
web: bundle exec puma -t ${PUMA_MIN_THREADS:-8}:${PUMA_MAX_THREADS:-12} -w ${PUMA_WORKERS:-2} -p $PORT -e ${RACK_ENV:-production}

#Gemfile
group :production do
    gem 'puma'
end
```

WEBrick is very slow, and takes a lot of time to process *every* resource individually. You'll be much better using a more "production-friendly" server on Heroku

---

**Error**

As mentioned, your error is here:

> /app/app/controllers/links_controller.rb:34: syntax error, unexpected
>   keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)

The typical case of `keyword_end` errors is the inability of the Rails application to parse the controller, as it's not got an end to the particular method in question.

The solution will be to check `links_controller.rb` at line 34 (or around it), to determine where there is a syntax issue, then you can do:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m "Links Controller Error"
$ git push heroku master
```